# How to sum up the individual fields of the object list and return the results as a single object

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have a method which is calculating nutrients for a list of object which we are receiving from API request call.

The method looks like:

```
public Nutrients nutrientsCalculator(DailyMeals dailyMeals) {

    String foodNamesForRequest = prepareFoodNamesForRequest(dailyMeals);

    HttpEntity<NutrientsBodyForRequest> requestBody = prepareRequestForAPICall(foodNamesForRequest);

    ResponseEntity<List<FoodNutritional>> response =
        //create request here

    if (nonNull(response.getBody())) {

      double totalFat = response.getBody()
          .stream()
          .map(FoodNutritional::getTotalFat)
          .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
          .sum();

      double totalProtein = response.getBody()
          .stream()
          .map(FoodNutritional::getProtein)
          .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
          .sum();

      double totalCarbohydrates = response.getBody()
          .stream()
          .map(FoodNutritional::getTotalCarbohydrate)
          .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
          .sum();

      double totalDietaryFiber = response.getBody()
          .stream()
          .map(FoodNutritional::getDietaryFiber)
          .mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue)
          .sum();

      return Nutrients.builder()
          .carbohydrates(totalCarbohydrates)
          .protein(totalProtein)
          .fat(totalFat)
          .dietaryFiber(totalDietaryFiber)
          .build();
    }
    return new Nutrients();
  }
```

My FoodNutritional.class looks like:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
class FoodNutritional {

  @JsonProperty("food_name")
  private String foodName;

  @JsonProperty("brand_name")
  private String brandName;

  @JsonProperty("serving_qty")
  private Integer servingQuantity;

  @JsonProperty("serving_unit")
  private String servingUnit;

  @JsonProperty("serving_weight_grams")
  private String servingWeightGrams;

  @JsonProperty("nf_calories")
  private Double calories;

  @JsonProperty("nf_total_fat")
  private Double totalFat;

  @JsonProperty("nf_saturated_fat")
  private Double saturatedFat;

  @JsonProperty("nf_cholesterol")
  private Double cholesterol;

  @JsonProperty("nf_sodium")
  private Double sodium;

  @JsonProperty("nf_total_carbohydrate")
  private Double totalCarbohydrate;

  @JsonProperty("nf_dietary_fiber")
  private Double dietaryFiber;

  @JsonProperty("nf_sugars")
  private Double sugars;

  @JsonProperty("nf_protein")
  private Double protein;

  @JsonProperty("nf_potassium")
  private Double potassium;
}
```

My solution in method works but I started thinking If it is possible to rid off this `sum` stream method boilerplate for this approach.

All I want to achieve is summing single fields: `totalFat`, `protein`, `dietaryFiber`, `totalCarbohydrate` and return them as a components fields of a new object.

I will be grateful for suggestions on how to improve the quality of the current version of the code.

Edit:

On the weekend I spent a moment to found a different, additional approach that will meet the requirements and is a little bit more functional. Finally, I created two static methods like:

```
private static Nutrients reduceNutrients(Nutrients n1, Nutrients n2) {
    return Nutrients.builder()
        .protein(n1.getProtein() + n2.getProtein())
        .carbohydrates(n1.getCarbohydrates() + n2.getCarbohydrates())
        .dietaryFiber(n1.getDietaryFiber() + n2.getDietaryFiber())
        .fat(n1.getFat() + n2.getFat())
        .build();
  }

  private static Nutrients fromFoodNutritionalToNutrients(FoodNutritional foodNutritional) {
    return Nutrients.builder()
        .dietaryFiber(foodNutritional.getDietaryFiber())
        .carbohydrates(foodNutritional.getTotalCarbohydrate())
        .fat(foodNutritional.getTotalFat())
        .protein(foodNutritional.getProtein())
        .build();
  }
```

and after all I used it like:

```
Stream<FoodNutritional> foodNutritionalStream = Optional.ofNullable(response.getBody()).stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream);

Nutrients nutrients = foodNutritionalStream
        .map(NutrientsCalculatorService::fromFoodNutritionalToNutrients)
        .reduce(NutrientsCalculatorService::reduceNutrients)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new CustomException("custom_exception");
```

Nonetheless, greetings for `@Koziołek`, `@Nir Levy` and `@Naman` for being my muse. Thanks for every single commitment.

Comment: Take a look at the [reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#reducing-U-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) in Java streams. You'll have to create an zero-initialized identity (initial state / accumulator), then reduce the stream with a binary operation that adds fat, proteins, etc. to the accumulator.

Comment: @madhead Another interesting approach, I will check this approach surely because I was not using this Collectors method yet.

Comment: It's already here, in [Nir Levy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58337761/750510). IMHO, it's the most performant as it will iterate your collection only once, summing all the nutritions.

Comment: @madhead When I was writing this answer I havent seen this answer. Now, in one moment I received multiple options. Thanks again for your commitment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let introduce class `NutritionAccumulator`:

```
class NutritionAccumulator{
    private double fat = 0.;
    private double carbs = 0.;
    private double fiber = 0.;
    private double protein = 0.;

    public NutritionAccumulator() {
    }

    public NutritionAccumulator(double fat, double carbs, double fiber, double protein) {
        this.fat = fat;
        this.carbs = carbs;
        this.fiber = fiber;
        this.protein = protein;
    }

    public NutritionAccumulator add(NutritionAccumulator that){
        return new NutritionAccumulator(this.fat + that.fat,
        this.carbs + that.carbs,
        this.fiber + that.fiber,
        this.protein + that.protein
        );
    }
}
```

And now we can write simple stream reduce:

```
Optional.ofNullable(response.body())
.stream()
.reduce(
                        new NutritionAccumulator(),
                        (acc, fudNut) -> new NutritionAccumulator(
                                fudNut.getTotalFat(),
                                fudNut.getTotalCarbohydrate(),
                                fudNut.getDietaryFiber(),
                                fudNut.getProtein()
                        ).add(acc),
                        NutritionAccumulator::add

                );
```

And finally you can pass result from above to builder.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Stream.reduce` method for that, just need to create a `NutrientsAggregator` that will know to add the values from `FoodNutritional` to itself and sum everything

```
public class NutrientsAggregator {
   private double calories;
   private double totalFat;
   private double saturatedFat;
   private double cholesterol;

   public NutrientsAggregator addFoodNutritionalValues(FoodNutritional foodNutrional) {
      this.calories += foodNutrional.getCalories();
      this.totalFat+= foodNutrional.getTotalFat();
      this.saturatedFat+= foodNutrional.getSaturatedFat();
      this.cholesterol+= foodNutrional.getCholesterol();

      return this;
   }
}
```

and than:

```
NutrientsAggregator result = response.getBody()
          .stream()
          .reduce(new NutrientsAggregator(), 
                  (aggregator, food) -> aggregator.addFoodNutritionalValues(food);
```

Comment: Best answer, as it requires only one collection iteration.

Comment: @Nir Levy Thanks for your answer. Are you sure that there is no misprint? I cannot use the method `addFoodNutritionalValues` in my stream. IntelliJ suggests creating this method in the FoodNutritional class. Maybe I suppose add this class `NutrientsAggregator` as an inner class in the FoodNutritional class?

Comment: @Martin - no `public` on your class is intentional? in any case, I wrote it here, not on ide, so might be a small typos or mistakes. it's more of a general idea to explain the gist of it

Comment: @NirLevy It's not a problem, I have a one single package responsible for one thing. `aggregator` and `food` is FoodNutritional type and after all, I cannot call this method on `aggregator`. IntelliJ try to force me to create method in FoodNutritional class instead of call it from accumulator class `NutrientsAggregator`

Comment: You cannot use the 2-parameters `reduce()` method if the result is not of the same type as the Stream's elements.

Answer (score 3):

How about using a `Supplier<Stream<T>>>` to create a reusable `Stream` something like :

```
Supplier<Stream<FoodNutritional>> foodNutritionalSupplier = () -> Optional.ofNullable(responseBody)
        .stream()
        .flatMap(List::stream);
return Nutrients.builder()
        .carbohydrates(foodNutritionalSupplier.get().mapToDouble(FoodNutritional::getTotalCarbohydrate).sum())
        .protein(foodNutritionalSupplier.get().mapToDouble(FoodNutritional::getProtein).sum())
        .fat(foodNutritionalSupplier.get().mapToDouble(FoodNutritional::getTotalFat).sum())
        .dietaryFiber(foodNutritionalSupplier.get().mapToDouble(FoodNutritional::getDietaryFiber).sum())
        .build();
```

where `responseBody` corresponds to the `response.getBody()` in the question.

---

Or further to using a utility to abstract out the core logic, such as :

```
private Nutrients nutrientsCalculator(List<FoodNutritional> responseBody) {
    Supplier<Stream<FoodNutritional>> foodNutritionalSupplier =
            () -> Optional.ofNullable(responseBody).stream().flatMap(List::stream);
    // should ideally be as simple as 'responseBody::stream'
    return Nutrients.builder()
            .carbohydrates(sumNutrition(foodNutritionalSupplier, FoodNutritional::getTotalCarbohydrate))
            .protein(sumNutrition(foodNutritionalSupplier, FoodNutritional::getProtein))
            .fat(sumNutrition(foodNutritionalSupplier, FoodNutritional::getTotalFat))
            .dietaryFiber(sumNutrition(foodNutritionalSupplier, FoodNutritional::getDietaryFiber))
            .build();
}

private Double sumNutrition(Supplier<Stream<FoodNutritional>> foodNutritionalSupplier,
                            ToDoubleFunction<FoodNutritional> nutritionTypeFunction) {
    return foodNutritionalSupplier.get().mapToDouble(nutritionTypeFunction).sum();
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach. In the first one everything seemingly is ok but line `.flatMap(List::stream);` is underlined with classic message `nonstatic method cannot be referenced from a static context` Unfortunately this collection is wrapped by ResponseEntity so I think that there is missing one additional flatMap operation, right?

Comment: @Martin Given the `responseBody` is an equivalent of type `List<FoodNutritional>` and one is using Java-11, it should ideally be inferrable. As I pointed in the answer as well, *`responseBody` corresponds to the `response.getBody()`*

Comment: You right, I didn't notice your additional comment below.